# Google Play: Is there any plan to allow management saleable items through an API?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

For in-app purchases on Android, I'm reading this manual: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

It says: ***"In all cases, you define your products using the Google Play Console."***

Is there any plans to make a Create/Read/Update/Delete interface for these items via HTTP API?

Comment: You would have to ask Google that question. There is no way any can/should speculate here.

Comment: For feature requests try opening an issue in [this page](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).